How to upload media to Display Video 360 using the .NET API client?
I'm communicating with Google's Display & Video 360 Service API from my .NET application. To achieve that, I'm using the Google.Apis.DisplayVideo.v3 package:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client
Specifically: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.DisplayVideo.v3/Google.Apis.DisplayVideo.v3.cs
I'm trying to figure out how to upload custom bidding algorithm scripts through the API
If I understand the process correctly, it should consist of two steps:
First, an instance of CustomBiddingAlgorithm needs to be created on Google servers. This instance will serve as a wrapper/metadata for the actual script. The creation can be achieved via the following endpoint: https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v3/customBiddingAlgorithms/create
Lastly, the actual python script should be uploaded and associated with the previously created CustomBiddingAlgorithm instance. The following endpoint should be used to do so: https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v3/customBiddingAlgorithms/uploadScript
I can finish the first step without any issues (in other words: I can create an instance of CustomBiddingAlgorithm programmatically and see it listed in the account). However, it is not clear to me how exactly the second step should be executed.
As for the actual code, this is my best attempt at implementing step #2:
// Assumes that step #1 (creation of the CustomBiddingAlgorithm instance) has already been processed successfully
public async Task UploadCustomBiddingAlgorithmScript(long advertiserId, long algorithmId, string scriptContents)
{
    var service = await GetDisplayVideoService();

    var uploadScriptRequest = service.CustomBiddingAlgorithms.UploadScript(algorithmId);
    uploadScriptRequest.AdvertiserId = advertiserId;
    var uploadScriptResponse = await uploadScriptRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    if (uploadScriptResponse == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uploadScriptResponse.ResourceName))
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to get upload URL");
    }

    // TODO: upload scriptContents somehow
}

Until this point, everything works. I can await the uploadScriptResponse, which is an instance of CustomBiddingScriptRef. This instance will have a real value stored in its 'ResourceName' property. I understand that I should use this retrieved ResourceName to somehow upload the actual script contents, but I'm not sure how.
The most obvious route would be to use the Media.Upload method of the DisplayVideoService class (defined on line #17666 of the generated class here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/66d8ca56c5bb9888bf597c49273b9ff1375534e4/Src/Generated/Google.Apis.DisplayVideo.v3/Google.Apis.DisplayVideo.v3.cs#L17666 )
But I'm not sure that this is indeed the correct way as the parameters of this method expect an instance of GoogleBytestreamMedia, and there doesn't seem to be a way of storing the actual script contents in that.
I would be super helpful if someone could nudge me in the correct direction because I'm really stuck at this point :)
